# How can i do UDP Socket Programming in C

Tags: c, sockets, udp

Here i want to do UDP Socket programming in C.

I have one device i want to send some message on my device from host machine. so i want to make this thing via UDP socket Programming.

So Can Any body suggest me the way how can i achieve this goal.

I want to do UDP socket programming.(Client and Server and send Message to device using this).

thanks

Comment: Let me google that for you:  tons of examples here http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/textcode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of sites that gives examples on how do that:

For example, the following site:

[UDP Example](http://www.abc.se/~m6695/udp.html)

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

[Socket Programming in C/C++](http://net.pku.edu.cn/~course/cs501/2011/code/BSD_Socket.t/sockets.pdf)